# How to change mat-raised-button color if there are multiple buttons in a div?

Tags: angular

**[EDIT] The solution is in the comment section.**

I want to change a color of a mat-raised-button, but to have a different color for every single button. I have the following situation:

```
<div *ngIf="visible" class="dialog">
  <button (click)="openEditDialog()" color="accent" mat-raised-button>Edit fields</button>
  <button (click)="update()" *ngIf="showSaveCancel" color="primary" mat-raised-button>Update</button>
  <button (click)="cancel()" *ngIf="showSaveCancel" color="warn" mat-raised-button>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The 'primary' and 'warn' options suit my needs for the 'Update' and 'Cancel' buttons, but I need to make the 'Edit fields' button green. Is there a way to make that button green, with the buttons to stay in the same div?

Comment: You could define a new color palette and then say `color='myPalette'`. Another option is to edit button CSS

Comment: Can you please clarify how to edit the button with CSS? If I edit it in a way to make .mat-raised-button background color green, I'm going to get all buttons background color green. I want to make just one of them with a green background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I've found, so if any of you guys have a similar issue, read further, the explanation is at the end:

**Original code:**

```
<div *ngIf="visible" class="dialog">
  <button (click)="openEditDialog()" color="accent" mat-raised-button>Edit fields</button>
  <button (click)="update()" *ngIf="showSaveCancel" color="primary" mat-raised-button>Update</button>
  <button (click)="cancel()" *ngIf="showSaveCancel" color="warn" mat-raised-button>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**New code:**

```
<div *ngIf="visible" class="dialog">
  <button (click)="openEditDialog()" color="green" mat-raised-button>Edit fields</button>
  <button (click)="update()" *ngIf="showSaveCancel" color="primary" mat-raised-button>Update</button>
  <button (click)="cancel()" *ngIf="showSaveCancel" color="warn" mat-raised-button>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, all I've done is to add a custom name to color value to the 'Edit fields' button, from "accent" to "green". And then in CSS, I added

```
.mat-green {
  color: white;
  background-color: forestgreen;
}
```

And that's it, I hope it helped someone. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.greenButton {
  background-color: green;
}
.greenButton:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
...
</style>

<button class="greenButton" ...>
```